# Internet sharing over AirPort

Tags: macos, airport, internet-sharing

In MacOS X 10.6, is Internet sharing over AirPort implemented as NAT or full-blown routing? The backing wired network is a corporate one, Ethernet with DHCP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't find anything definitive from Apple, but the [detailed testing done here by Princeton University](http://www.net.princeton.edu/mac/internet-sharing-x/) indicates that it's NAT (and that it's inappropriate for use on their campus, so might well be for your scenario too).

Answer (score 1):

Type:

```
ps ax | egrep '[ /](PID|boo|nat)'
```

in a `Terminal` or `xterm` window.
Fire `InternetSharing` from the `System Preferences`. Type the same
command again.

You will be able to see the different daemons which `InternetSharing`
spawns under 10.6 or 10.7 .

The answer is…
`InternetSharing` does 3 things:

- address translation through `natd`,
- address distribution through `bootpd`,
- routing through `route` (but I got this information through other means of investigation).